# Loading script dynamically with data attribute

Tags: javascript

I want to load this script dynamically and it contains data attribute

```
<script class="podigee-podcast-player" 
  src="https://cdn.podigee.com/podcast-player/javascripts/podigee-podcast-player.js" data-configuration="https://pt.podigee.io/embed?context=external">
</script>
```

I tried this. But it didn't work for me. Is it a correct way to set data-configuration attribute? Where I am making mistake?

```
var script = document.createElement('script'); 
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.async = true;
script.src = 'https://cdn.podigee.com/podcast-player/javascripts/podigee-podcast-player.js';
script.class = 'podigee-podcast-player';
script.dataset.configuration = 'https://pt.podigee.io/embed?context=external';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(script, s);
```

Comment: Did you look into the developer tools on how the script is embedded? It should show up in your HTML

Comment: Try simple adding attribute `script.setAttribute('data-configuration', 'https://pt.podigee.io/embed?context=external')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the data attribute isn’t the actual problem here, but you tried to set the class (which appears to be important) incorrectly.

That part needs to be `script.className = 'podigee-podcast-player';`

Comment: That's an issue too, did not notice.

Answer (score 0):

When you type

```js
var s = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(script, s);
```

the `s` parameter in the `appendChild()` method doesn't exist when `appendChild()` is called. Also `appendChild()` only needs the child element as argument.
Try doing

```js
var s = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(script);
```

Also you only need to type `var s =`  if you plan on using the value that `appendChild()` returns, which, according to the documentation, is the child element itself.